# Can I read registry permissions? If so, how?

Tags: c#, permissions, registry

I am experimenting with registry functions because I don't understand them yet. I am attempting to create two registry keys, one with read-only permission, and one with read-write permission. I have successfully created them, but I want to check that they have the proper permissions before I move forward. I know I could simply test them by attempting to manipulate them, but I'm thinking that there must be a way to just read a registry key's permissions.

Does anyone know how to do that?

I am using VisualStudio and writing in C#. I've been trying to search "Read registry key permissions", "get key permissions" and such things, but I just get a lot of information on WHAT read-only permission is and things like that. Useful, but not helpful to this specific task.

The code for creating those keys is as follows:

```
//Create ROKey - "ReadOnlyKey"
RegistryKey rKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("ROKey", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
//Create WRKey - "ReadWriteKey"
RegistryKey wKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("WRKey", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

Edit:

At the suggestion of @itsme86, I have included the following code:

```
var security = rKey.GetAccessControl();
var rules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
foreach (var rule in rules.Cast<AuthorizationRule>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(rule.IdentityReference.ToString());
}

security = wKey.GetAccessControl();
rules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
foreach (var rule in rules.Cast<AuthorizationRule>()){
    Console.WriteLine(rule.IdentityReference.ToString());
}
```

Unfortunately, I am now getting the following error:

Error   1   'System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\DoD_Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\RegistryManipulationTest\RegistryManipulationTest\rKeyTestClass.cs 249 40  RegistryManipulationTest

I'm using the "System" and "Microsoft.Win32" namespaces. Is there another namespace I should be using?

Edit 2:

I've added "Using Linq;" to the program, and now it recognizes "Cast". The downside is, it doesn't recognize the AuthorizationRule type. I tried "using System.Web.Configuration;", the namespace for the AuthorizationRule class, but now I'm told "The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is [RegistryKey.GetAccessControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w66447a(v=vs.110).aspx). It will return a [RegistrySecurity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.registrysecurity(v=vs.110).aspx) object which you can call [GetAccessRules()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.commonobjectsecurity.getaccessrules(v=vs.110).aspx) on. There's also a corresponding [SetAccessControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) method if you want to change the permissions.

You'll obviously need to be running your application with elevated permissions.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("software"))
{
    var security = key.GetAccessControl();
    var rules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

    foreach (var rule in rules.Cast<AuthorizationRule>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rule.IdentityReference.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly seems to point me in the right direction, but when I call GetAccessControl(), it returns: "System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity", same output for either key. I'm not sure how to make use of it, though it is definitely more than I had! Would you mind providing an example so I can see its implementation?

Comment: @MrSpudtastic I've updated my answer with example code.

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented it, but I'm getting an error now. I've edited the original question to provide more details. I think it's almost there!

Comment: @MrSpudtastic: `Cast()` is bundled with LINQ, you can either add the reference, or just do the cast yourself without a helper function.  For example: `foreach (var rule in rules) { Console.WriteLine((rule as AuthorizationRule).IdentityReference.ToString()); }`

Comment: Hmm... with that line, it's telling me "The type or namespace name 'AuthorizationRule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Make sure you add `using System.Security.AccessControl;` at the top of the file.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)